# Convert scientific notation back to numbers in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had data in Excel like

```
7540006
7540447
```

But when I import the data into `SQL Server`, it is saved as

```
7.54001e+006
7.54045e+006
```

So now when I try to convert it to back to original state, it's not ending up with the correct value.

I have tried following queries for conversion

```
declare @a varchar(40)
set @a = '7.54001e+006'

declare @b decimal(27, 12)

SELECT @b = CONVERT(REAL, @a, 2)

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(str(@a))), LTRIM(STR(@a))

SELECT CAST('7.54001e+006' as REAL)
```

and the output I am getting is addition of 3 to original value for all methods
i.e.

```
7540010
7540050
```

How do I convert it back to original state ??

Comment: How did you import it? And what datatype did you import it to?

Comment: It looks like it already lost the extra decimal places, so you will have to re-import it.

Comment: Agree with @Chuck, and I'd change that to TEXT in Excel if you are running into these formatting issues so it doesn't truncate your decimal into scientific notation. Then you can convert it

Comment: [Casting Scientific Notation (from varchar -> numeric)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6750771/5690722)

Comment: ... and you can not convert it to the exact values because precision has been lost before import.

Answer (score 29):

Try the following query which gives the exact value

```
select CAST(CAST('7.54001e+006'  AS FLOAT) AS bigint)
```

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old answer but i've been stuck on this problem and i'm wondering why does this solution work? - I was playing with numeric / real / text and they either were in scientific notation or rounded numbers, this worked beautifully but I was wondering why?

Comment: I'm assuming this value has been imported to a column.  For this to work, 1) the new column was created with the info above, 2) the current column was updated to a blank, 3) that column was altered as the proper varchar value, 4) the original then updated with the updated values from the query above, 5) the new column dropped, and 6) the transaction committed.

Answer (score 4):

All data is stored as Unicode `string 255 (DT_WSTR)` in `excel`.

Read `excel` data as `Unicode` form. then do conversion in `ssis` or `database` using.

```
SELECT CAST('7.54001e+006' as REAL)
```

**In excel data source  >> connection manager >>Data access mode 
  == QUERY**

```
     SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]
```

Comment: Warning: You could be losing the original number using this method. EG if your number was 6196335264001, and it imported as 6.19634E+12, the result will be 69196340000000 instead of the more accurate number.

Answer (score 0):

when you will save in database that time convert value into `toString()` like

```
Convert.toString(7540006)
```

then it will save original value in database.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

ISNULL(TRY_CONVERT(numeric(19,5),'9.8E-4'), CAST(CAST('9.8E-4' AS REAL) AS numeric(19,5)))

This ensures that only values that can't convert naturally are cast as REAL