# Casting Scientific notation from Varchar to Decimal in mysql

Tags: mysql, string, casting, decimal

On a mySQL database, in a dataset all values are stored as varchar, show amounts of Euro and look like this: 'EUR 2.5E+2', 'EUR 56.95', 'EUR 1E+2'

Now, I want to make it useful again and convert this into decimal for further calculation, but can't figure out how to do it.

I have tried to follow the suggested solution to this question:
[Casting Scientific Notation (from varchar -> numeric) in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750021/casting-scientific-notation-from-varchar-numeric-in-a-view)

However, I failed to replicate the solution as a query, view or stored procedure, much less adapt it to my problem.

I really hope someone can help me out here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't have been a `varchar`. However, you might have a chance by trying to convert without `EUR` and then, if needed, concatenating it back again.

Comment: How did you manage to get into this mess? Anyway, removing the 'EUR " (and maybe adding 0) should fix it

Comment: Yeah, well... the kind of analysis I am trying to do had low priority, when the system was built. Devs said they will change it, though :-B

Answer (score 3):

Thank you very much Rick James, your solution works quite well. 
However, I prefer to explicitly cast the substring as decimal:

```
CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.amount, ' ', -1) AS DECIMAL(5,2))
```

Now I can carry out calculations on the result (see comment below Rick's answer).

Comment: To avoid roundoff errors for _money_, do use `DECIMAL`.  (But be cautions about the `5`; make sure it is big enough.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('EUR 2.5E+2', ' ', -1) + 0;

->

250
```

Caution:  This *assumes* there is one space, and the numeric value is after the space.

Comment: looks pretty good, thank you! However, subtraction has surprising results. Say, when this code reaturns 92.06 and I subtract 100, I get -7.939999999999998.

Comment: That is a general problem with `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`.  Such fields are precise to some number of significant bits; but when converted to decimal, things like that happen.  Your particular example gained 3-4 bits of precision; then the conversion pulled noise in.  There are lots of discussions about floating point issues.  If you are storing dollars/Euros and cents, use `DECIMAL` to avoid such.  Which, of course, is what your answer does.