# How do I convert 9E-5 Scientific notation to INT (0.00009)

Tags: t-sql, scientific-notation

How do I convert 9E-5 Scientific notation to INT (0.00009) in SQL, the majority of records are all INT values with this rogue record I'd like to handle it in the load stage.

Comment: A decimal value cannot be an int. Also representation shouldn't matter, they are stored as numbers and not strings in the database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting Scientific Notation (from varchar -> numeric) in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750021/casting-scientific-notation-from-varchar-numeric-in-a-view)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT convert(numeric(18,18),convert(float(53),'9E-5'))
```