# How to cast varchar value to decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a column that is currently set as `nvarchar(max)` and I want to convert the column to `decimal(38,2)`. The problem I am running into is that a few of the millions of rows are in the format of `-1.943E12` and because the `E` is present I get an error, `Cannot convert nvarchar into numeric`, when I try to cast the column into a decimal. Is there anyway to do this?

```
CREATE TABLE practice (cost nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO practice values ('123'),('44232.99'),('43.4432'),('1.943E12')

SELECT CAST(cost as decimal(32,2)) FROM practice
```

What I'm ultimately trying to do is insert data from a staging table (where all columns are nvarchar(max)) into a table with appropriate datatypes. I kept getting an error, so after digging through each of the 40 columns, I found 5 columns where this scientific notation occurs. Any advice on how to do this at scale without having to check each column?

```
INSERT INTO practice_corrected_datatypes
SELECT * FROM practice
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Casting Scientific Notation (from varchar -> numeric) in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750021/casting-scientific-notation-from-varchar-numeric-in-a-view)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numeric cannot convert from exponential format, but float can. Therefore you could do this by going via float. For example:

```
print cast(cast('1.943E12' as float) as decimal(38,2))
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming you have `try_parse()` and `try_cast()`

```
SELECT try_cast(try_parse(cost as float) as decimal(32,2))
FROM practice
```

The advantage is that they return NULL instead of failing. You could probably get by with just the inner try_parse()

```
SELECT cast(try_parse(cost as float) as decimal(32,2))
FROM practice
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

update p
set cost = cast(cast(cost as float) as decimal(32,2))
from practice p
where cost like '%E%'